# Wait for component mapping to complete before proceeding

Tags: javascript, reactjs

We have a component which performs a map loop to create a list of components.
This list of components has some expensive calculations in there thus takes a while to create.

Trying to show a loading component while this map completes creating all the components.

Its not like I am making some async call to fetch data here to wait for it and show/hide loader.

It's just the component taking time to create and looking to show a loader while it creates the list of components.

How could I show this loader, how to wait for the mapping to complete? Tried to play around with wrapping it inside a `Promise.all` but it complains that that is not a valid `jsx`.

```
import React from 'react';

const Main = ({items}) => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true); 

  /*
  // can't do this. It would become an infinite spinner
  if (isLoading) return <Loading />
  */

  return (
    <div>
      <Component1 />
      <Component2 />
      <div>
        {/* wait for this mapping to complete. Show a loader whiile it loads. setIsLoading(false) once done */}
        {items.map((item, i) => (<ExpensiveComponent/>))} 
      </div>
      <Component3 />
      <Component4 />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Main;
```

Comment: You can't out of the box. The only things you can try is enable server side component if you are using nextjs. The best is to try to understand why your ExpensiveComponent is expensive.

Comment: By "expensive" do you also mean *"blocking"*?  If so then that's going to prevent the browser from doing anything at all while those operations are processing.

Comment: @David It currently causes the page to kind of freeze up and lag while that component properly renders.

Answer (score -1):

Please let me know if this is what you were looking for. You can add a function that will get the data and set the loading status at the same time.

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState('not-loaded')

// Function
const getData = () => {
     setLoading('loading')
     someMethod.get(someData)
       .then(() => { 
          setLoading('loaded') 
  
         // Do something

         
       }) 
       .catch(err => console.log(err))


}
```

Then in your html

```
{loading === 'loading' && <Spinner />}
{loading === 'loaded' && <ExpensiveComponent />}
```